# VBA não aparece as opções e Métodos automaticamente

Tags: vba

Sou novo aqui, e já peço desculpas pela dúvida "banal", mas estou pesquisando há um bom tempo isso.

Uso o VBA pelo EXCEL, e não consigo ativar a opção do texto se autopreencher ao escrever uma função ou método conhecido.

Assim, tenho tido muita dificuldade em saber os métodos que certo objeto possui.
Já ativei o Autoverificar Sintaxe e demais opções:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Assim, minha dúvida é: Eu preciso adicionar alguma extensão específica para isso, ou apenas habilitar algo que não estou achando?

Obrigado pela atenção.

Comment: Qual é o objeto em que não aparece a lista de propriedades e métodos?

Answer (score 0):

A opção é essa `Autolistar membros`, que está marcada no print que você mandou.

Uma opção de fazer isso manualmente é clicar com o botão direito e selecionar `Listar propriedades/métodos`, mas é um porre fazer isso à mão:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Mas tem um detalhe: se você estiver tentando usar isso com um objeto que faz parte de uma biblioteca não referenciada, não vai aparecer mesmo. Tente com `ThisWorkbook.`, que integra a biblioteca do próprio Excel, e veja se aparece.

Se não aparecer, há alguma configuração profunda perdida aí, além da minha resposta.